# Build Problems when moving from VS2008 Prof to VC++ Express 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors, visual-c++-2008-express

I have just taken over game development from my friend. The development is done using VC++.

The Code worked perfectly when it was build on Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition.

Without any changes, I tried to build the code in VC++ Express 2008 Edition and its throwing numerous errors (more than 100). All are either:

```
 error C2953: 'std::tr1::_Result_of1<Rx(_thiscall _Arg0::* )(void),_Farg0&>' : class template has already been defined C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xxresult  106
```

or

```
error C2995: 'std::tr1::_Mem_fn1<_Rx,Rx(_thiscall _Arg0::* )(void),_Arg0> std::tr1::mem_fn(Rx (_thiscall _Arg0::* )(void))' : function template has already been defined C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xxmem_fn  47
```

Since all the errors seem due to the include files and not from the Code written, I am stuck.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It looks to me like there's a duplicate definition for a class template. Make sure that you're not including the same header file twice.

Comment: @Cody If so shouldn't that throw an error when Compiling/building in VS2008 Professional Edition. But thanks, I'll have a look at it

Comment: I suspect the code you haven't won't compile in the Professional Edition, either. Something must have gotten messed up during the migration. Perhaps you have double copies of a particular source file or something. The error messages appear to give you line numbers and file names at the very end. Best thing I know to do is trace the problems through the code. There's no known bug in the Express compiler; it's exactly the same one as in the Professional edition.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Nebula2 :)
In `nsystem.h` remove `"#define __cdecl"`
This error can also occur if somewhere appears defines like:

> #define __cdecl
>
> #define volatile
>
> #define const